# Executing Neo4j Cypher Query (by Java) Using existing Dataset

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I directly made a neo4j dataset by using neo4j console ("localhost:7474")
(as you knew "graph.db")
I wanna execute Cypher Query (by Java) Using this data.

I already saw the example from

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/cypher/src/test/java/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/JavaQuery.java

I just wanna use this way but directly use existing data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Neo4j in embedded mode i.e. it runs within the same jvm as your application, you can access it using:

> GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new
>   GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DBPATH)

where DBPATH is the path to the database you created using Webadmin. You can find that path in your neo4j install directory/conf/neo4j-server.properties
(The property name is org.neo4j.server.database.location)

Once you have instantiated your graphDb, you can execute Cypher queries as described in http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html

If you are not using Neo4j in embedded mode and want to connect to the existing server running on port 7474, you can use the java rest binding: https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this few months ago. It's very minimalist in order to be easy to understand !
https://github.com/bendaizer/neo4j_cypher_java_template

You just need to give the path to your database directory (with you data), and your cypher query. I didn't had time to write something better, so you need to recompile for each new query !